# Thoroughly Uninstalling XAMPP with its phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I installed XAMMP to practice php language, then uninstalled it, now I want to reinstall it again. When I uninstalled it, the phpMyAdmin folder and all of its items weren't deleted. I tried to delete all XAMPP related files and folders from Registry Editor but did not find any related files !!
What can I do now, and if I reinstall XAMPP, will I face any problem?

Comment: no problem, you can install xampp, actually you can simply use zip version and double click on `setup_xampp.bat`

Comment: what about if I reinstall xampp with no usingn zip version , is there any proplem?

Comment: no problem will occur